# How to combine 2 databases (db files) into one database file?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 db files `la.db` and `lb.db`. I want a single db file, like `final.db` which would combine both `la.db` and `lb.db` databases. I am using sql lite.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use some native client in Ubuntu or similar for other Os, export them in a sql dump and reimport in a new one, OR you can simply write a small routine / program in c# that uses sqlite implicit, and select + insert and manage exception...

it depends on what data type you have into the sqlite.

Comment: I am using sql lite to achieve in windows 7 platform. It would be very helpful for me if you give me a detailed description of what you told me. Thanks

Comment: how is the structure of your sqlite?